Prove that $(1+1/n)^n\to e$ from this definition of $e$.
Suppose I start from the "integral" definition of $e$. I.e., $e$ is the unique positive real number such that
$$\int_1^e \frac{1}{x}\,dx=1.$$
How do I prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e,$$
using just this definition and nothing else?

Related Prove That $\int_{1}^{e}\frac{1}{t}dt=1$ Without the Use of Logarithms where the converse is proven

My answer to the question above includes an answer to this one.

For each $x>0$, define
$$
L(x) = \int_1^x \frac1t\ dt.
$$

Prove that $L(xy)=L(x)+L(y)$ for $x,y>0$.
Deduce from this that $L(x^n)=nL(x)$ for $x>0$ and $n \in \Bbb Z^+$.
Also, prove that $L$ is differentiable and that $L'(x)=1/x$ for $x>0$.

Then, by continuity of $L$,
\begin{align}
L\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1+1/n \right)^n \right) 
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} L \left( \left( 1+1/n \right)^n \right) 
 = \lim_{n \to \infty} nL \left( 1+1/n \right) \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{L(1+1/n)-L(1)}{1/n} \\
&= L'(1) = 1.
\end{align}
Since $L(e)$ is also $1$ and $L$ is injective,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1+1/n \right)^n = e.
$$

+1. and if at the beginning you write $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=L^{-1}\left(L\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)\right)$, and proceed with the remaining steps you wrote, and then at the end invoke continuity of $L^{-1}$, then this furthermore proves the existence of the limit (rather than the other standard approach of proving existence of this limit).

It seems easier to prove $L(x/y)=L(x)-L(y)$ for $x,y>0$ by a change of variables $u=yt$, $du=ydt$ in the integral equation for $L(x/y)$.

Given that
$$\int_1^e \frac{1}{x}\,dx=1$$
we define for $x>0$
$$\log x =\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\,dt $$
such that $\log 1=0$ then $\log e=1$ and prove that it is continuos, differentiable, injective and such that

$\log(x)+\log(y)=\log(xy)$
$y\log(x)=\log(x^y)$

Now
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\log(1+x)}x=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\int_1^{1+x} \frac{1}{t}\,dt}x\stackrel{H.R.}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{1+x}=1$$
then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac1n}=1\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e  $$

How do you reach the final conclusion?

@Michael By continuity  and injectivity of $\log$ function.

I do not follow. Specifically, how do you obtain a result about bringing $n$ into the exponent from your fact $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n\log(1+1/n) = 1$? Indeed $n\log(x)=\log(x^n)$, but that is a property that is developed in the azif00 solution. Are you just assuming that is true?

@Michael Ah ok, yes of course we need to prove this property for $\log$ function $A\log B = \log A^B$.
